# Print result from database only 5 result in each page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to include a page that extracts some information from database into a home page and show results into home page, page by page, for example, the page who extract info print 20 result and it's too long to affiche all those results into the home page, so I want to make a section or anything into the home page and print only 5 result by 5 result and add a next and previous button to print all the others result without reloading the official home page,

there is my simple home page:

```
<html>
<!-- other objects in page-->
<section id="cnt">
  <?php include('extract_infos.php'); ?>
</section>
</html>
```

and the page who extract infos to affiche him into the home page "extract_infos.php" is:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

  try{
    $sql1 = "SELECT `name`, `ps`, `image` FROM `profile`";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die("Error: 
      ".mysqli_error($con));

   while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_NUM)){ ?>       
      <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $row1[0]; ?></p>
  <?php
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result1);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo `Exception reçue : `.$e;
  }
  ?>
```

the second page print for example 20 result and she print all of them into the home page, 
what I want is: limit print by page and print only 5 results and when I click into next the home page doesn't reload but I see the next 5 result...

please I need help

Comment: follow the procedure given [here](https://codepen.io/terf/post/php-pagination) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm) and make appropriate changes on the front-end side.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of *pagination* which can be done in many ways. For example you can do something like this,

- Each time send the page number to your backend
  -- `$pageNumber`
- And then change your query to this:

  ```
  $startingFrom = (int)$pageNumber*5
  $sql = "SELECT `name`, `ps`, `image` FROM `profile` LIMIT $startingFrom,5";  # Retrieve 5 rows each time, starting from $startingFrom
  ```

For more information you can have a look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) page and follow these tutorials: [1](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928), [2](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination) or many similar ones you can find on the Web!